# Php não reconhece botão css

Tags: php, css

Não estou conseguindo colocar o botão `css` dentro do código `php`, alguém poderia me ajudar nessa?

```css
.botao01{
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E0E0E0, #F9F9F9 70%);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E0E0E0, #F9F9F9 70%);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E0E0E0, #F9F9F9 70%);
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E0E0E0, #F9F9F9 70%);
     background: linear-gradient(bottom, #E0E0E0, #F9F9F9 70%);
     border: 1px solid #CCCCCE;
     border-radius: 3px;
     box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3),
                   0 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     color: #616165;
     display: block;
     font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: bold;
     line-height: 25px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #FFF;
     padding: 5px 15px;
     position: relative;
     width: 80px;
}
 
.botao01:before{
     border: 1px solid #FFF;
     border-radius: 3px;
     box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 12px -4px rgba(70, 70, 70, .2),
                   inset 0 3px 2px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
     content: "";
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     padding: 5px;
     position: absolute;
    }
 
    .botao01:after{
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
     border-radius: 2px;
     content: "";
     bottom: 15px;
     left: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     position: absolute;
    }
 .botao01:active{
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
     top: 4px;
    }
    .botao01:active:before{
     border: none;
     box-shadow:none;
    }
```

```html
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
          $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
          while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)){
     echo '<div class="col-md-4 bottom-cd simpleCart_shelfItem">';
     echo '<div class="product-at ">';
     echo  '<a href="single.php"><img class="img-responsive" src="Produtos/Imagens/Camisetas masculinas/'.$ln['imagem'].'" />';
     echo  '<div class="pro-grid">';
     echo     '<span class="buy-in">Buy Now</span>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo '</a>';
     echo '</div>';
     echo '<p class="tun">'.$ln['nome'].'</p>';
     echo '<a href='#' class='botao01'>Comprar</a>';
     echo   '</div>';
    }
      ?>
```

Comment: Estou sem entender, serio. Seu problema possivelmente está nessa linha dentro do `while` ... `echo '<a href='#' class='botao01'>Comprar</a>';` era pra `href` e `class` estar entre Aspas duplas.

Comment: Como já dito pelo @WéllingthonM.deSouza, é erro de digitação. Precisa separar as aspas do PHP e as do HTML de alguma maneira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você usou aspas simples no `a.botao01` escapando o texto do `echo`.

```css
.botao01{
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E0E0E0, #F9F9F9 70%);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #E0E0E0, #F9F9F9 70%);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #E0E0E0, #F9F9F9 70%);
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #E0E0E0, #F9F9F9 70%);
     background: linear-gradient(bottom, #E0E0E0, #F9F9F9 70%);
     border: 1px solid #CCCCCE;
     border-radius: 3px;
     box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3),
                   0 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     color: #616165;
     display: block;
     font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: bold;
     line-height: 25px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #FFF;
     padding: 5px 15px;
     position: relative;
     width: 80px;
}
 
.botao01:before{
     border: 1px solid #FFF;
     border-radius: 3px;
     box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 12px -4px rgba(70, 70, 70, .2),
                   inset 0 3px 2px -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
     content: "";
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     padding: 5px;
     position: absolute;
    }
 
    .botao01:after{
     background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
     border-radius: 2px;
     content: "";
     bottom: 15px;
     left: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     position: absolute;
    }
 .botao01:active{
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
     top: 4px;
    }
    .botao01:active:before{
     border: none;
     box-shadow:none;
    }
```

```html
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
          $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
          while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)){
     echo '<div class="col-md-4 bottom-cd simpleCart_shelfItem">';
     echo '<div class="product-at ">';
     echo  '<a href="single.php"><img class="img-responsive" src="Produtos/Imagens/Camisetas masculinas/'.$ln['imagem'].'" />';
     echo  '<div class="pro-grid">';
     echo     '<span class="buy-in">Buy Now</span>';
     echo  '</div>';
     echo '</a>';
     echo '</div>';
     echo '<p class="tun">'.$ln['nome'].'</p>';
     echo '<a href="#" class="botao01">Comprar</a>';
     echo   '</div>';
    }
      ?>
```